# log4j2 highlight first line only in the console

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, console, highlight, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to log to the console and file as in this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - Line %L: %msg%n}"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - Line %L: %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="error"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="info"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The problem is only the first line in the netbeans console appears in red while the remaining lines are black as in the following picture.

Any help will be appreciated

Update:I tried the project with eclipse and all lines appeared in black
[image: console output]

Comment: This is only on Netbeans, not on DOS or unix console, correct?

Comment: I tried only on netbeans, I don't believe DOS accepts colors

Comment: This does not answer your question, but PatternLayout supports `highlight{pattern}{style}` options for ANSI colors. For this to work in DOS you need http://jansi.fusesource.org/